# Some Growth Conditions and Locally Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, stochastic-differential-equations

A function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is Locally Lipschitz if when restricted to a compact subset it is Lipshitz see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity .

I have been told that if a function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfies the following growth conditions :

\begin{align}
 \| f(x) - f(y) \| \leq C \| x-y \| \big( 1 + \| x \|^{r-1} + \| y \|^{r-1} \big), ~~~~~~~(1)& 
\\
 \| f(x) \| \leq C \big( 1 + \| x \|^r\big).~~~~~~~(2)&~~~r= 1,2,3\ldots 
\end{align}

then it is Locally Lipshitz, $\textbf{Question :}$ does anyone know if this is true?

$\textbf{Question :}$ Equation $(2)$ says that the function $f$ is growing at most polynomially, what does $(2)$ tells us about $f$? Some intuition about the role that these conditions play when $f$ governs an ODE $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=f(x(t))$ (or SDE) would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the first question, only (1) is sufficient: Let $K$ be compact. Then $K$ is bounded and thus $|x| , |y|\le M$ for some $M$. So (1) implies 

$$\| f(x) - f(y)\| \le C(1+2M^r) \|x-y\|$$
for all $x, y\in K$. Thus $f$ is Lipschitz on $K$.

Comment: @ArcticChar So is (1) equivalent to Locally Lipschitz, or does it tells us something more?